# Ubuntu 15.10 Bluetooth not working - Qualcom Atheros AR9485

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

After lots of questions and bug reports I think I finally got my weird Bluetooth problem.

I have Lenovo G510 with Ubuntu 15.10.
Since I had Ubuntu 14.10 my Bluetooth sometimes worked and sometimes didn't.

Sometimes the laptop doesn't show any sign of Bluetooth features,
 not in `dmesg` and not in `rfkill`.

The problem is that this "sometimes" are rather very long :\ 
So I need help to understand the problem.

Thank You.

Comment: When Bluetooth isn't working, does `sudo service bluetooth restart` help? I need to do this occasionally on a G580 running 15.04.

Comment: It's not changing anything